# Remove math fragments from buffer in org mode

Tags: org-mode, math

With `org-latex-preview` (should be used from version 9.3 on) I can generate math previews of latex fragments of a section in org mode, but how can I remove them?

Comment: `org-latex-preview` will display a preview of the fragment at point. It is only when point is *not* on a fragment that it will display previews of all fragments in the section (as the doc string you quote in your answer states).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an `C-u` prefix:

From the docs:

```
(org-latex-preview &optional ARG)

Toggle preview of the LaTeX fragment at point.

If the cursor is on a LaTeX fragment, create the image and
overlay it over the source code, if there is none.  Remove it
otherwise.  If there is no fragment at point, display images for
all fragments in the current section.

With a ‘C-u’ prefix argument ARG, clear images for all fragments
in the current section.

With a ‘C-u C-u’ prefix argument ARG, display image for all
fragments in the buffer.

With a ‘C-u C-u C-u’ prefix argument ARG, clear image for all
fragments in the buffer.
```

Comment: If you are happy with this answer (which presumably you are since you wrote it :-) ), that's fine: it works. But note that the doc string contains nuances that are lost in your "just use a `C-u` prefix" summary.